# Silver badge for answering your own question *before* asking it

Tags: discussion, badge-request

While talking with a coworker I realized that very often I answer my question through the act of composing and email (but not sending) or writing a SO question (but not posting).

Working through the details and doing the additional research often reveals the answer, at which point I either abandon the post or post it anyway and immediately post the solution.

Since answering your own question is covered by the Self Learner badge, I think there should be a badge for abandoning questions before they are posted.

**I realize it would be tricky (or impossible) to implement** in a way that's not easily susceptible to abuse but nonetheless, I think it's a neat idea. *And might spark some other good (possible) ideas.*

If nothing else, it could spur other badge ideas (e.g., using the related questions list that shows up while asking a question to find your answer without asking a new question).

Comment: Talk to the duck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to implement, but requires the [direct-to-brain interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21053/21058#21058).

Comment: yes, that would help...but you know how Jeff feels about dependencies

Comment: The linking-to-Welbog meme strikes again!

Comment: Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19507#19507

Comment: Be careful though, or you might see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19502#19502

Answer (score 4):

You know you're talking about the most-easily-gamed badge in history?

`boom` *A computer crashes.*  — "Hey, look, a silver badge."

Comment: Yes, I realize that. It's more of an idea that I thought could lead to *better*, more reasonable (?) ideas

Answer (score 3):

No. Is their a "bad idea of the day" badge for meta? Joel couldn't be more correct. This would be waaaay too easy to game.

Comment: wow, who cares if someone games a badge

Comment: +1. If only there was a "good idea of the day" badge on meta! I'd have nominated your badge suggestion pronto. C'est la vie.