# No reputation for upvote given?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

After [answering a question earlier on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667757/alert-box-running-first/1667776#1667776), I realized that the upvotes to my answer do not increase my reputation. I've checked and I am sure that neither the question nor my answer are set as community wiki.

Checking my latest activities, it shows 2 in the top half of the green box, but nothing in the lower half, where reputation would be.

#### Here's a screenshot of my rep activity:

> [screenshot of reps http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/3803/usermaurisrecentstackov.png](http://img410.imageshack.us/img410/3803/usermaurisrecentstackov.png)

Any idea what happened?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've got 196 reputation today. You're at your cap:

[image]

Comment: It's times like this that I wish I took my tablet PC into work today so that I could draw even more silly things.

Comment: Who needs a tablet when the jitteriness of the mouse does just fine?

Comment: Well, what I would end up drawing will look exactly the same, but I'd have drawn it *faster* with a tablet.

Comment: I use my mouse in my right hand, and my tablet's pen in my left hand, so things would look a little bit different. I can draw letters better with my left hand than my right hand. "Drawing letters", otherwise known as "writing".

Comment: Liar! You don't have hands! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21053/stack-overflow-needs-direct-to-brain-interface-for-post-human-users

Comment: Oh welbogging frakkle! I mean cerebral lobes! I use my right lobe for my mouse, and my left lobe for my tablet pen!

Comment: Can't you just hold the pen in your nostril?

Comment: I don't have a neck, and I can't wiggle my nose, so I don't see how that would help.

Comment: oh nice one! I always thought the total reputation from the day was calculated from the recent page.

Comment: I draw with a touchpad, so don't complain!

Comment: Why to limit the reputation score? what is wrong in gaining points :-(

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you were not over your reputation limit for the day?

Looking at your reputation graph, it looks like this is a strong possibility.

Comment: I hardly reached 60 today. It seems that my reputation is also dropping 2 by 2 - and the changes does not reflect on my recent page.

Comment: It seems you are wrong. You should have looked at the graph as I suggested.