# Receiving empty rep

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No reputation for upvote given?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28402/no-reputation-for-upvote-given)

My statistics say I've made 187 rep from `2009-11-13 00:00:00Z` to `2009-11-13 23:59:59Z` on [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com/).

But since the last few answers I seem to keep receiving   rep. Why?

[image: Weird rep]

Comment: You're at your rep cap. Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28402/

Comment: The cap is at 200 not 187 right?

Comment: The cap is also horribly buggy. You're at your rep cap. Don't worry about it.

Comment: But shouldn't I receive `"0"` rep for the answers then, not `""`?

Comment: Would you rather have 0 added to your reputation or nothing added to your reputation? Is the distinction really so confusing?

Comment: It confused me enough to post here. And, buggy or not, 187 is pretty far away from 200.

Comment: Well, in reality you're probably not really very far off from 200, unless you do a lot of downvoting. Do you do a lot of downvoting?

Comment: I've made 2 downvotes today. My statistics for from 00:00 to 23:59 today contain one red box with "1" in the first row and "-2" in the second row.

Comment: Well then you've probably gained 198 rep today, and the rep page isn't showing it right. That's always what happens. It happens to everyone. Like I said: big ol' dupe.

Answer (score 3):

That only happens if you've hit your daily cap; if your time zone is not UTC, your day is different from the server's day.

Comment: Doesn't `Z` stand for UTC?

Comment: Yes, Z means 'Zulu Time' or zero time, which is TZ=0, or UTC.