# How do people respond so quickly?

Tags: discussion, responses

I'm amazed at how quickly I receive answers!
What is it that people are doing?
Is there some sort of monitoring program that beeps or something when a new question has been asked that is tagged with the subject that you specify?

Comment: Check the lamp next to you.

Comment: 2,000 questions per day may seem like a lot, but there are 600,000 unique visitors per day, which means each question gets, on average, 300 people who see the title at some point as they are monitoring the front page.

Comment: Out of those 300 people, 1-2 of them understand the problem and solution well enough to jump in an answer it, all within minutes of you publishing the question.

Comment: @AdamDavis The majority of those unique visitors go from a search engine directly to an already-answered question of interest to them; they are not monitoring new questions.

Comment: Is there an RSS feed of the latest (tag) questions? Maybe people have a toaster notification when someone asks a new question in their favorite categories.  For instance, SO sent me an SMS with your comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think <kbd>F5</kbd> does most of the job. :)

But also and most importantly, there simply is an awful lot of people browsing SO at any given time.

Comment: I think [someone mentioned something like 600k uniques a day](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com), so divide that by 86400 seconds in a day, there's always somebody watching the pages ...

Comment: What would it be a beatiful lot of people?

Comment: @Alejandro an *awesome* lot of people would work too :)

Answer (score 6):

Some people use the sort order **newest question**, look for questions they know something about and hope to type quicker than others.

Next question please.

Answer (score 3):

[Neural implants.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21053/stack-overflow-needs-direct-to-brain-interface-for-post-human-users)