# Eeek! I can vote to delete all questions here on Meta!

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

Just noticed this: ([source question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187205/152859))

> [image]

After quick check on other question old and heavily downvoted and not closed, I can indeed cast a vote and it's recorded.

I see the link on **all questions including upvoted questions** here on Meta. <strike>and Stack Overflow too</strike>.

I double checked; did not get any diamond.

Not sure it's related and don't remember if it was showing delete votes before, but the ["Delete and Undelete votes" tab in 10K](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=) tools is empty.

Comment: Ssssst, don't tell them. I have been abusing this for some time now. Wait, I could just delete this...

Comment: Is it on main too?

Comment: @Sklivvz: No, just here on meta for me.

Comment: @Sklivvz yes on main too for me. Wait, checking again. Edit: nope, but can swear I had "delete" link on main site too minutes ago.

Comment: I don't see the `delete` link (and I don't have access to mod tools on meta) so unable to replicate at my end.

Comment: @Darren yeah, guess you must have at least 10K to start with so you can delete *closed* questions.

Comment: Voted to delete because reasons.

Comment: @Manishearth http://i.stack.imgur.com/fR26M.gif!

Comment: Delete votes cleared! ;)

Comment: Hey who cast **another** vote??!@!@

Comment: And now it is gone...why did you have to spoil it?! If this would have hit main, we could have done the biggest clean-up since...since...ever! Imagine the frontpage after the cleanup...JUST THINK OF THE FRONTPAGE!

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby well, it lasted for few minutes there and when I think of what could have happened... [this is the result](http://www.desicomments.com/wallpapers/desert/desert_28.jpg)! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: *Imagine a very wise, intelligent, philosophical and deep statement here how beautiful the desert can be, and how it is sometimes better to have a desert instead of everything else.*

Comment: There are days when voting to delete all the questions on meta is tempting...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My bad, refactoring oops.

The mighty Nick Craver has written a patch, which I am sending out *right now*, please verify the fix :-)

Comment: Only on MSO can I break the site, *not* fix it, and get upvoted :-)

Comment: Noooooooo...all this power, lost forever!

Comment: Yup, fixed. The rep is for the hard work fixing what you broke! :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Nick fixed it. ;)

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby so if he wanted the rep he should have come here himself, not send a messenger! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd He's out at the moment.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Please don't tell me he wrote the fix on his phone or something...

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby no, he wrote it before leaving. I wouldn't be surprised if there were some other patches done on his iPad though.

Comment: @Sklivvz why spoil the fun? I was happily imagining Nick sending you the patch via brain waves... :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd we asked him to stop sending brainwaves. He's too smart and we were getting nose bleeds.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: You mean [something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21053/stack-overflow-needs-direct-to-brain-interface-for-post-human-users)?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I knew I missed something!

Comment: -1 This is not a bug fix, it's a feature retraction.

Comment: By the way, you can tag [meta-tag:status-completed] now. :-)

Comment: By the way, can you put `[status-deferred]` on the linked to question by @M.NightDemonbobby that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ryan that should be status-completed but it's sekrit

Comment: Nope, I can still see the delete link in the picture.