# 10K+ users can search any user's deleted content

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, deleted-posts

Despite the message:

> Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content

I'm able to search a specific user's deleted content using a search query such as:

```
user:X deleted:1
```

Where `X` is the user ID:

[image: s1]

As far as I know not even 10K+ users should be able to do this.

Comment: Whoa. That's a HUGE bug. Reminds me of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187208/eeek-i-can-vote-to-delete-all-questions-here-on-meta)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup. It seems like the expected behavior of each is straight swapped with the other.

Comment: Actually, it's only a 10k privilege to begin with, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253674/152859). <10k users should just see the ordinary search results, as if "deleted:1" is the search string.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have 10K+ on that site, that's apparently not a problem, the second user (10K-) can't even search his own.

Comment: True, like I said the ability to search your own deleted content is a 10k privilege, so that part is not a bug

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah my bad, I misread your comment: I took that part down.

Comment: Cheers, took it out of title as well now. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, obviously I forgot about the title :)

Comment: And... it's fixed here on MSE. Now you can put anything as user:[id] but you'll get only results for your own.

Comment: *As far as I know not even 10K+ users should be able to do this.* Goddamnit, thanks for spilling the beans.

Comment: @Won't Yeah I know. Downvoting is legit here. :D

Comment: Maybe you should create another bug report...

Comment: I agree with @Braiam that's worth a new bug report

Comment: @Braiam Moved the new issue to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/10k-users-can-still-search-any-users-deleted-content)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Moved the new issue to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/10k-users-can-still-search-any-users-deleted-content)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A fix will be deploying shortly - there's an args parsing race I hadn't considered here when locking down the user scope.

Comment: Too bad. Can I post a feature request to restore this? ;)

Comment: @Pat you'll have better chance by nominating yourself to become moderator, or better yet - hired to SE team and get diamonds all around. :-D

Comment: Let's get me a diamond! :)

Comment: Aw, that's too bad.

Comment: Well, just for fun I tried `deleted:all`...and that shows the user's deleted post among the non-deleted posts.

Comment: I was suggested to create a new post for this new issue; you can follow up on the new post [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/10k-users-can-still-search-any-users-deleted-content)

Comment: Okay, but now I can't see my deleted posts where I don't have 10k. Is it by design?

Comment: Why a user cannot see his deleted posts? What is the reason that SO is making decisions for the user and hides his owns posts? Do you see a chance at least the own deleted posts remain visible?