# 10K+ users can [still] search any user's deleted content

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, deleted-posts

Following up on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270554/302251) post;

Despite the message:

> Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content

I'm able to search a specific user's deleted content using a search query such as:

```
user:X deleted:all
```

Where `X` is the user ID:

[image: s1]

As far as I know not even 10K+ users should be able to do this.

Comment: You surely deserve the hacker badge for  all those efforts! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard If they leave the privilege to me I'll call it even. :D

Comment: Wow, very nice find.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fun fact: `deleted:all` is not actually a valid search argument. We only accept values `1, 0, true, false, yes, no`.

Fun fact #1.5: The above fun fact isn't technically correct. `deleted:all` is acceptable and produces results that include both deleted and "live" posts.

Fun fact #2: the fact that it was a not-clearly-true-or-false is what broke this. `deleted:hedgehog` or `deleted:banana` would have produced the same result. :)

I fixed this harder, so `deleted:all` should work again but the results for searches by 10k users will still be constrained appropriately.

Comment: I love your "Fun fact" way of explaining this.  :)  Another example of why it's vital to [always sanitize/verify user input](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Ah! Yes, fun facts all. Sad fact: apparently you fixed that for good. :(

Comment: Missed those fun facts. [tag:feature-request]: use them more! :D