# Ask & Answer question through voice recording

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, answers

I was wondering if we could ask a question by recording our voices. It would become much easier and comfortable to ask questions. If someone is too lazy to write a big question, he can simply leave a voice question, and everyone could listen and answer to the question by either typing or recording.

This is a feature request and I hope you all would agree with me.

Comment: Umm; no, I do not agree with you at all. First; this would make for horrible questions. Second, if someone *really* wants to do this, the right place is via voice recognition on their system - not via the website.

Comment: Being "too lazy to write a big question" is a sketchy motive, and sounds like it would contain elements of questions that are commonly put on-hold and closed. Most Stack Exchange communities expect that the asker will have already done some groundwork and present that in their question... this feature request seems to work against that.

Comment: Giving a new shade of meaning to "unclear what you're asking" -- "no, really, I _can't even make out the words_".

Comment: We expect high quality questions. Being too lazy seems to be at odds with putting the effort into high quality.

Comment: [Stack Overflow needs direct-to-brain interface...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21053/165773)

Comment: You can't `grep` a recording.

Comment: Whenever I feel self loathing I'll come back to this question and read it to punish myself.

Comment: You can use your own voice to text program locally to help you start writing out your question, assuming you take the time to edit the results as needed.

Comment: You should be thankful that I can only down-vote by clicking - if I could verbally down-vote, you'd be crying right now.

Comment: @gnat - we'd have a lot of blank questions

Comment: The community sentiment is clear, but +1 for forward thinking, in a way.  Will we be typing things in 20 years?

Comment: @John Maybe not, but people most likely won't be *listening* to questions

Comment: @Lamak That's what speech-to-text conversion is for.  But right, I don't agree with the listening-to-questions part of it.

Comment: And we'll have to typewrite all the recorded code to reproduce the problem? It'll take ages to receive an answer... Congratulations on the bad idea of the week, great chances of winning the year award!

Comment: Can we haz a morse code help line too...perhaps smoke signals, carrier pidgin.. ? Maybe embedded videos for programming assistance through teh medium of dance..?  Believe it or not, these idea are not much worse than the suggested voice question/answer, which is bad for all the reasons already mentioned, plus many many *many* more that would become apparent with more thought and the system in play.

Comment: @John: *" Will we be typing things in 20 years?"* [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987182/improving-the-way-we-write-code)

Comment: I'd like a service where I can mail in a question by carrier pigeon. Encrypted, of course, with a separate key that will come via a different pigeon.

Comment: Then why didint you voice record this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[You have 1 unread message.](http://users.content.ytmnd.com/1/c/8/1c8159dfba503b2db576bf48b5b6ef57.wav)

Comment: Nice. Somebody had to do this. I was actually _too lazy_ -- it was easier to type something in.

Comment: Awesome!! That's what I am talking about.

Comment: May _the force_ be with you!

Comment: Then you think yes!

Answer (score 37):

No. Taking the effort to compose and type out a question is a basic first step to making it intelligible to the people from whom you want help. It's not failproof, but it can help clarify the issue in your own mind, which makes it more likely that others will understand your situation. People speaking without preparation lose track of what they are talking about, clear their throat and constantly use -- what are those things called -- oh, filler words, repeat things, <sub><sup>mumble</sup></sub>, and, just like this guy I ended up talking to on the bus the other day, will tend to ramble -- Christmas, he wouldn't shut up. Anyways... There's a far better chance of producing a top-quality question in written form, and we only want the best here.

Not to mention that, on SO at least, there's programming code involved in nearly every question and answer. *Nobody* wants to try to listen to you read your code out loud.

Finally, and maybe most importantly, **voice recordings aren't searchable**. The major impetus for these sites in the first place was to provide an archive of solutions to problems that will be findable and useful to people in the future.

Answer (score 17):

Given all of the dialects and languages of our users, this doesn't seem reasonable. The recordings can't be edited for content. You can't write code in a recording. Who determines the length of the recording?

What makes these sites work is the ability to quickly get the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I have read a tutorial before, I will share some part to clarify some good points:

> Communication through text might encourage shy people to speak out and
>   help them to bring out their ideas. It might help people to say what
>   they really want to say without worrying being intimidated by others.
>
> People put their ideas in a more concise way through text. They try to
>   get to the point when they type. Their ideas become clearer and more
>   precise via text, whereas real life spoken conversations are more
>   casual and less thought through.

Source: http://beyonddistance.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/text-vs-voice-based-communication-in-second-life/

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

There are flaws in your idea:

- I don't think people would like to recive scary/monsterus voices, or 7 year olds screaming "Help me! Help me!"
- If the grammar/formatting is bad, it can not be fixed.
- People don't want to hear cursive language.

Answer (score 0):

This is already possible if you use the dictation feature of your mobile phone

Comment: ^ 100% posted with the dictation feature of my mobile phone; proof: https://youtu.be/dlT3pfnxW0s