# Suggestion for Code Insertion

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

The Insertion of codes can be made more easy to use. As a new user, it becomes confusing to use at times

Comment: Ehm, what? Easier? We have a button for that. And what is your question now?

Comment: How? How do you wish it to become easier? Easier than what?

Comment: I see that you inserted code just fine [in this answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20633994/447356) so really no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Oded Maybe he wants an auto detector that detect when you type code and auto-formats it for you ;P

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn - so, not a direct brain interface?

Comment: @Oded maybe. ;P

Comment: @Oded - Sounds like [Skeet's been beta-testing that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21058/135615).

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to insert code blocks, is to use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. If you want a code block, press enter, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, and then you can write your code block. If you want an inline code span `like this`, then don't press enter, but just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

This way looks like a very easy way, if you think there is an easier way, then please provide *which* way.

Comment: Maybe by sending a telepathic command?

Comment: The second way won't work when there are multiple lines of code. You should do this instead: 1) Press enter 2) Select the code block 3) Press `Ctrl` + `K`.